# Puppet Apt module: dependency cycle

Tags: vagrant, puppet

Using  `puppetlabs/apt` in a puppet provisioner for vagrant.  the module is installed in puppet/modules and I'm getting a strange Dependency cycle error.
the code in the manifest file:

```
# Run apt-get update when anything beneath /etc/apt/ changes
#taken from https://blog.kumina.nl/2010/11/puppet-tipstricks-running-apt-get-update-only-when-needed/
exec { "apt-get update":
command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update",
onlyif => "/bin/sh -c '[ ! -f /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin ] || /usr/bin/find /etc/apt/* -cnewer /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin | /bin/grep . > /dev/null'",
}

package {
    ["build-essential","apache2","git","python","python-dev","python-setuptools", "python-pip"]:
    ensure => present,
    require => Exec["apt-get update"],
    }

class { 'apt':

        }
include apt

apt::builddep { ["python-imaging","python-lxml"]:
    require => Class['apt'] 
 }

class {'nodejs':

}
include nodejs

package {"less":
    ensure => present,
    provider => 'npm',
    require => Package['npm'],

}
```

I actually noticed similiar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568748/dependency-cycle-with-apt-source) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384733/puppet-issue-with-aptsource-and-stages), but not with a satisfying answer.
The error message:

```
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Package[python-virtualenv]/require: requires Package
[python-pip]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Package[python-virtualenv]/require: requires Package
[python-setuptools]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Apt/File[configure-apt-proxy]/notify: subscribes to E
xec[apt_update]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Apt/Anchor[apt::update]/require: requires Class[Apt::
Update]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Apt/File[sources.list.d]/notify: subscribes to Exec[a
pt_update]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Package[python-pip]/require: requires Exec[apt-get u
pdate]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Apt::Builddep[python-lxml]/Exec[apt-builddep-python-
lxml]/notify: subscribes to Exec[apt_update]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Package[apache2]/require: requires Exec[apt-get upda
te]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Package[python-dev]/require: requires Exec[apt-get u
pdate]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Package[npm]/require: requires Anchor[nodejs::
repo]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Package[nodejs]/require: requires Anchor[nodej
s::repo]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Package[python]/require: requires Exec[apt-get updat
e]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Package[build-essential]/require: requires Exec[apt-
get update]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Apt::Builddep[python-imaging]/require: requires Clas
s[Apt]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Package[git]/require: requires Exec[apt-get update]←
[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Package[less]/require: requires Package[npm]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Package[sphinx]/require: requires Package[python-pip
]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Apt::Builddep[python-imaging]/Anchor[apt::builddep::
python-imaging]/require: requires Class[Apt::Update]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Package[python-setuptools]/require: requires Exec[ap
t-get update]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]/Apt/File[sources.list]/notify: subscribes to Exec[apt
_update]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Apt::Builddep[python-imaging]/Exec[apt-builddep-pyth
on-imaging]/notify: subscribes to Exec[apt_update]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Apt::Builddep[python-lxml]/Anchor[apt::builddep::pyt
hon-lxml]/require: requires Class[Apt::Update]←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: /Stage[main]//Apt::Builddep[python-lxml]/require: requires Class[A
pt]←[0m
←[1;35merr: Could not apply complete catalog: Found 1 dependency cycle:
(Anchor[apt::update] => Class[Apt] => Apt::Builddep[python-lxml] => Exec[apt-bui
lddep-python-lxml] => Exec[apt_update] => Class[Apt::Update] => Anchor[apt::upda
te])
Try the '--graph' option and opening the resulting '.dot' file in OmniGraffle or
 GraphViz←[0m
```

any known workaound? solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest is a little wonky.

1. You define your own `Exec["apt-get update"]` although the `apt` module declares an `apt_update` you could use
2. `class { 'apt': } include apt` is redundant. Avoid the `class { }` syntax unless you need to declare parameters.

Those are rather cosmetic issues. What may conceivably be breaking your dependencies is

```
apt::builddep { ["python-imaging","python-lxml"]:
    require => Class['apt'] 
}
```

That require doesn't seem to make sense, I propose you let the `apt` module take care of its own internal dependencies/ordering, then it should Just Work.

```
apt::builddep { ["python-imaging","python-lxml"]: }
```

Comment: Sure :-) but it wasn't closed or updated, so I figure some insights may yet be of help - if not to you then perhaps some future reader.